Reference Request: Analogue of eigenvalues but only positive part
Given a matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ I am interested in solutions to the following equation:
\begin{equation}
[Dv]_+ = v
\end{equation}
For nonnegative vectors $v\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$, where $[]_+$ sets negative parts of $Dv$ to $0$.
It's like an eigenvector equation with eigenvalue one, but with this added nonnegative thing.
I feel like someone must have studied this already, but my google-fu is not good enough to find it. Is there a keyword I should be googling? Or good results on this?
